# Unable to retrieve List of Dates from Dynamic Number of DatePicker controls in .Net Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: .net, datepicker, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-datepicker

I have multiple DatePickers on page and they are set with initial values correctly using Model passed from Controller.

However, when I pick a date, the value is not stored in Model and when trying to receive in Controller, the value is always empty.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstDate, Model.FirstDate.ToString(), 
                        new {@class = "input-group datepicker date",
                        id = "datepicker@i", type = "text", 
                        style = "max-width:123px;min-width:123px" })
```

JS>

```
@{var startDate = @Model.SelectedDates[0].EventDate;}
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            startDate: '@startDate',
            endDate: '+365D',
            weekStart: 1,
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                if (dates.indexOf(formatDate(date)) < 0)
                    return {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                else
                    return {
                        enabled: true
                    }
            },
            format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',

        });
```

The Model passed on to controller has FirstDate as DateTime but it is always default date. Date selected using picker is never set.

EDIT>
I now understand that the list being part of View's model is not a list being passed back to the Controller. Is there a way of building the list within the View without calling back using Ajax?

I cannot think of other way for storing dates for unknown number of datepickers.

Comment: What is actually getting posted back? `F12` to see.

Comment: Are there other date pickers on the page? Right now, the only thing connecting your date picker to the text box is the class, "datepicker", and if there are other elements with that class, you're not going to get the results you want.

Comment: yes, there will be other datepickers based on the model.SelectedDates.Count(). I have tried to retrieve value by mapping the datepicker result ti explicit string Value in Controllers' parameters. This one worked. It does not work when I try to store values to Model.SomeListOfObjects[i].StringRepOfDate. The List is null when I retrieve it. It should be containing elements of original View's Model.ListOfObjects respectively

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround if somebody was interested how to deal with unknown number of parameters being passed back to the Controller without refreshing the page and without using AJAX

I define every datepicker like so:

```
<input type="text" class="input-group datepicker date" name="@pickerReference"/>
```

These can be created based on the list you feed from controller via Model.YourPickerListDates

When submitting the form back to controller, instead of hardtyping every picker into the Model or Controllers' parameters, you add `IFormCollection form` side by side with your Model being returned.

In controller you can iterate through the formCollection or get every date selected like so:

```
string value = Convert.ToString(form["pickerReference"]);
```

I couldn't think of better solution, since the Model being returned must have the strongly defined values. If you don't want to use formCollection to return your values, you would probably need to call Ajax or something.